# SQL Server machine account failed to open database

Tags: sql-server, localsystem

I have an ASP.NET Web application hosted in IIS. Application is running under LocalSystem account. Application is trying to connect to a database on SQL Server with `Integrated Security=True`. I have added the machine account to sql server and also made it sysadmin. I have provided access to the specified database. Still I am getting error: Failed to open the explicitly specified database.

Please help.

Comment: Integrated security = True so that means LocalSystem has to be a user on your domain. I am guessing it is not. So better not use Integrated security but provide user and pass in your connectionstring

Comment: LocalSystem account uses Machine account to access resources on network. So I have added Domain\Machine$ to my sql server logins. Error Message shows the same account name.

Comment: That wont help you. When using integrated security no logins on your sql-server are used, windows domain users are used. If you realy want to keep integrated security than user LocalSystem will have to be a domain user. Good luck with that

Comment: When Integrated Security= True, Windows account is used. When a machine joins a domain, an additional account with name [Domain\MachineName$] is also created in domain. LocalSystem uses this account when Integrated Security=True

Comment: Great then everything works then, right ?

Comment: everything works when IIS and SQL Server are on different machines. But not when they are on same machine.

Comment: That is indeed very odd. But is there a reason why you want to use integrated security and not want to use login/pass in the connection string ?